# Can I use multi-level nested generate statement?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm curious if using multi-level nesting of the `generate` statement is possible.
As far as I know, it's impossible.
Here is a very simplified problem that I want to find a solution for. Suppose there is a design composed of blocks in a hierarchy. For example, there are 32 grids, there are 64 blocks in each grid, and there are 1024 threads in each block. This is very weird and inefficient code, but can I do the code below using a nested `generate` statement?

```
// 32 grids, 64 blocks in each grid, 1024 threads in each block

initial begin
        grid0.block0.thread0.reset = 1;
end
initial begin
        grid0.block0.thread1.reset = 1;
end
...
initial begin
        grid0.block0.thread1023.reset = 1;
end

initial begin
        grid0.block1.thread0.reset = 1;
end
initial begin
        grid0.block1.thread1.reset = 1;
end
...
initial begin
        grid0.block1.thread1023.reset = 1;
end


...
        
initial begin
        grid31.block63.thread1022.reset = 1;
end
initial begin
        grid31.block63.thread1023.reset = 1;
end
```

I would be very happy if I could do something like :

```
genvar grididx,blockidx,threadidx;
generate for(grididx=0;grididx<32;grididx++) begin
generate for(blockidx=0;blockidx<32;blockidx++) begin
generate for(threadidx=0;threadidx<32;threadidx++) begin
        initial begin
                grid`grididx.block`blockidx.thread`threadidx = 1;
        end
endgenerate  
endgenerate
endgenerate
```

(I can generate code using a C program with print loops and include it of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is legal to use nested `generate` `for` loops, but you can not achieve what you want given your current design hierarchy.  For example, you have unrelated instances: `grid0` and `grid31`.  You gave the instances static names.

If you had created an **array** of instances (`grid[31:0]`, for example), then you could have used `generate` `for` loops for your assignments.  You would have also had to create instance arrays of `block` and `thread` as well.  Then, your assignment would look something like:

```
genvar grididx,blkidx,threadidx;
for(grididx=0;grididx<32;grididx++) begin
for(blockidx=0;blockidx<32;blockidx++) begin
for(threadidx=0;threadidx<32;threadidx++) begin
        initial begin
                grid[grididx].block[blockidx].thread[threadidx].reset = 1;
        end
end
end
end
```

The `generate/endgenerate` keywords are optional.  Also, you can not nest `generate` keywords like you tried.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 23.6 *Hierarchical names*:

> Names in a hierarchical path name that refer to **instance arrays** or
> **loop generate blocks** may be followed immediately by a constant
> expression in square brackets. This expression selects a particular
> instance of the array and is, therefore, called an instance select.
> The expression shall evaluate to one of the legal index values of the
> array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The current design (which other people have wrote) is not using array of instances so I figure I cannot use generate as I want to(I used C program to generate bruteforce code instead and included it in a testbench). But now it's clear to me.